# How to save widgets to cache when orientation of screen changes

Tags: android, layout, orientation, widget

Is it possible to save widgets to cache?  If so how can I go about doing this?  I made my application implement widgets and everytime the orientation changes the activity has to restart forcing the widgets to disappear.  If its not possible to save the widgets to cache, how can I make the widgets reappear when the orientation of a device changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try creating a `/res/layout-land` version of your widget and see what happens.

Comment: I'm not making a widget I'm making an application that hosts widgets